# Correct way with Macbook Pro trackpad to select from dropdown form?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, multi-touch, magic-trackpad

Having started to use a MacBook Pro with Catalina a lot more than a Mac Mini, I've had trouble trying to negotiate the trackpad after using a mouse for so long.

I want to be able to use a dropdown / select, like this example at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup but do not know the correct trackpad gesture for selecting it; I've done some light Google-ing but am unsure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If tap to click is on just tap. If not the bottom part of the trackpad is one big button, press it.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. If you're asking about the "secondary click" (aka "right click in mousey parlance) feature on the trackpad, set this up in `System Preferences`, `Trackpad` under the `Point and Click` tab. Make your selection under the `Secondary Click` item there.